# table is not updating on paypal by IPN on live server

Tags: php, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am using PAYPAL payment gateway in my php project and I am using sandbox account. I am updating my database table through IPN. Everything is working properly in my localhost. But on live server notify.php is not working, means IPN is not updating table. I also changed the notify url in live server.

**index.php is:**

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type='hidden' name='business' value='sb-sp6wa2712137@business.example.com'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='DigBizCard'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='amount' value='12'>
<input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>
<input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='https://yourdomain.com/payment_gateway/paypal/notify.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='https://yourdomain.com/payment_gateway/paypal/cancel.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='https://yourdomain.com/payment_gateway/paypal/return.php'>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="submit" name="pay_now" id="pay_now" Value="CLICK HERE TO PAY" style="border:0; font-size:16px; font-weight:600; background-color: transparent; color: #004aad !important; margin:0; padding:0;">
</form>
```

**notify.php is:**

```
<?php
// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);
// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "ipn.log");
// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode($value);
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}
// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.
//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}
// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $user_id = $item_number;

    include('../../operations.php');
    $obj = new DigbizOperations();
    
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    $isPaymentCompleted = false;
    if($payment_status == "Completed") {
        $isPaymentCompleted = true;
    }
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    if($isPaymentCompleted) {
         $update_payment_code = $obj->update_payment($user_id,$txn_id);
       if($update_payment_code == TRUE)
       {
           $show_payment_session = $obj->show_payment_session($user_id);
           if($show_payment_session != '' || $show_payment_session != '')
           {
           // entry in sales table for admin panel                        
          $show_payment_session = $obj->entry_in_sales_table($show_payment_session['id'],$show_payment_session['purchase_amt'],$show_payment_session['referral_id'],$show_payment_session['payment_date'],$show_payment_session['username'],$show_payment_session['digbizcard_id']);
           }
       }
        
    } 
    // process payment and mark item as paid.
    
    
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
?>
```

I opened **https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/**

and enter URL. After that message print **IPN was sent and the handshake was verified.**

But still on live server table is not updating.

Comment: is there any redirection during the process?

Comment: no. There is no redirection.

Comment: you should use paypal's ipn library, its easy to use as well as good demos are available

Comment: Basically you need to check your log file on the server, add more thorough logging if necessary and troubleshoot what is going on, whether it received data, whether it was able to verify that data, whether it was able to connect to the database, etc.  All this needs to be logged so you can pinpoint where it's going wrong and fix it.